# FB-style Menubar on bottom of page gets covered by content

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, menubar

I have a horizontal menubar attached to the bottom of my page (like FB has its bar on the top of the page) using

```
.bottom_menu {position:absolute; bottom:0px; z-index:100}
```

My main content in the page is placed inside a div box positioned absolutely.

```
.main_content {position:absolute; top:100px; left:75px;right:75px; z-index:100}
```

The problem is that if I have too many lines of content within the tabs, it appears **over** the menubar instead of pushing it to the bottom.

How do I structure this so that **the menubar always stays on the bottom of the screen**, say at least a couple of lines **below the last line of content** inside the main_content div?

Thanks, and apologies in advance if this is a very silly question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a container for footer menu and content section like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>MENU</li>
        <li>MENU</li>
        <li>MENU</li>
        <li>MENU</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

then set position of container `relative` and position of menu to `absolute`. set `padding-bottom` for container as height as menu for prevent content to cover menu.

content will increase height of container and footer menu will be bottom of container all time.

[**here is demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4bcxm/1/)

**CSS**

```
 ul, body, htnl{
     padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
div.container{
    position:relative;
    min-height:30px;
    background:#eee;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
ul{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:#aaa;
}
```